# Expanding ranking of column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Consider a sample DF:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,60,size=(10,3)),columns=["a","b","c"])
df["d1"]=["Apple","Mango","Apple","Apple","Mango","Mango","Apple","Mango","Apple","Apple"]
df["d2"]=["Orange","lemon","lemon","Orange","lemon","Orange","lemon","Orange","lemon","Orange"]
df["date"] = ["2002-01-01","2002-01-01","2002-01-01","2002-01-01","2002-02-01","2002-02-01","2002-02-01"]
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
df

    a   b   c     d1       d2    date
0   7   1   19  Apple   Orange  2002-01-01
1   3   7   17  Mango   lemon   2002-01-01
2   9   6   4   Apple   lemon   2002-01-01
3   0   5   51  Pine    Orange  2002-01-01
4   4   6   8   Apple   lemon   2002-02-01
5   4   3   1   Mango   Orange  2002-02-01
6   2   2   14  Apple   lemon   2002-02-01
7   5   15  10  Mango   Orange  2002-01-01
8   1   2   10  Pine    lemon   2002-02-01
9   2   1   12  Apple   Orange  2002-02-01
```

Trying to replace column `d1` with rank based on Group by column `d1` and `mean` of column `c`in expanding manner. For example, consider the following first 5 rows:

1. First row by default the value at index `0`, i.e `Apple` will be replaced with `0`
2. Second row, index `1`, the value `Mango` should be replaced by `0`, because considering only the first `2` rows of the DF `GROUPED_MEAN` for `Apple` will be 19 and `Mango` will be 17, so the value Mango at index `1` should be replaced by rank 0 since it has lower grouped mean.
3. Third row, index `2`, the value `Apple` should be replaced by `0`, because considering only the first `3` rows of the DF `GROUPED_MEAN` for `Apple` will be `(19+4)/2` and `Mango` will be 17, so the value Apple at index `2` should be replaced by rank `0` since it has lower grouped mean
4. Fourth row, index `3`, the value `Pine` should be replaced by `2`, because considering only the first `4` rows of the DF `GROUPED_MEAN` for `Apple` will be `(19+4)/2` and `Mango` will be 17, `Pine` will be 51, since Pine has the highest grouped mean of all the 3 categories- `[Apple, Mango, Pine]`, Pine will be given rank 2.
5. Fifth row, index `4`, the value `Apple` should be replaced by `0`, because considering only the first `5` rows of the DF `GROUPED_MEAN` for `Apple` will be `(19+4+8)/3` and `Mango` will be 17, `Pine` will be 51, since Apple has the lowest grouped mean of all the 3 - `Apple, Mango, Pine`, Apple will be given rank 0.

Expected Value of column d1:

```
0
0
0
2
0
0
1
0
2
1
```

Iterative Approach:

```
def expanding(data,cols):

    copy_df = data.copy(deep=True)
    for i in range(len(copy_df)):
       if i==0:
          copy_df.loc[i,cols]=0
       else:
          op = group_processor(data[:i+1],cols,i)
          copy_df.loc[i,cols]=op
    return copy_df

def group_processor(cut_df,cols,i):

    op=[]
    for each_col in cols:
       temp = cut_df.pivot_table("c",[each_col]).rank(method="dense")-1
       value = cut_df.loc[i,each_col]
       temp = temp.reset_index()
       final_value = temp.loc[temp[each_col]==value,"c"]
       op.append(final_value.values[0])

    return op

expanding(df,["d1"])
```

I am able do this iteratively through every row of the DF, but the performance is poor for large DFs so any suggestions on a more pandas based approach will be great.

Comment: "I am able do this iteratively" - great, please post the code for that.

Comment: @JohnZwinck edited the question with iterative approach

Comment: For the second row the grouped mean of mango is 17 while apple is 19, so why the mango is assigned `1` instead of `0`? Similarly at row 6 value should be 1.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma my bad, you are right for row 2, but for row 6 ```Mango``` is (17+1)/2 and ```Apple``` is (19+4+8)/3 and ```Pine``` is 51, so ```Mango``` should be replaced by 0.

Comment: By row 6 i mean to say at index 6.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma again my bad you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.expanding`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.expanding.html) with minimum window size of `1` on column `c`, and use a custom lambda function `exp`. In this lambda function we use [`Series.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) to group the exapnding window `w` by the column `d1` in the original dataframe and `transform` using `mean`, finally using [`Series.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html) with `method='dense'` we calculate the rank:

```
exp = lambda w: w.groupby(df['d1']).transform('mean').rank(method='dense').iat[-1]
df['d1_new'] = df['c'].expanding(1).apply(exp).sub(1).astype(int)
```

Result:

```
# print(df)

   a   b   c     d1      d2        date  d1_new
0  7   1  19  Apple  Orange  2002-01-01       0
1  3   7  17  Mango   lemon  2002-01-01       0
2  9   6   4  Apple   lemon  2002-01-01       0
3  0   5  51   Pine  Orange  2002-01-01       2
4  4   6   8  Apple   lemon  2002-02-01       0
5  4   3   1  Mango  Orange  2002-02-01       0
6  2   2  14  Apple   lemon  2002-02-01       1
7  5  15  10  Mango  Orange  2002-01-01       0
8  1   2  10   Pine   lemon  2002-02-01       2
9  2   1  12  Apple  Orange  2002-02-01       1
```

Performance:

```
df.shape
(1000, 7)

%%timeit
exp = lambda w: w.groupby(df['d1']).transform('mean').rank(method='dense').iat[-1]
df['d1_new'] = df['c'].expanding(1).apply(exp).sub(1).astype(int)
3.15 s ± 305 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
expanding(df,["d1"]) # your method
11.9 s ± 449 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Testing it on size (100000,)

Comment: @data_person As you are doing exapnding window calculations this will be going to take ample time, one option you can further improve the performance is by utilizing the multiprocessing. As you saw in the performance benchmark there is at least 4x speed up from your original method.

Comment: I tried that using joblib, with my approach I tried to parallelize the for loop. It still didnt improve the performance.

Comment: But again using multiprocessing in this scenario will be a daunting task.

Comment: It is taking more than 10 mins for size (100000). Can you give me any pointers on how to use multiprocessing with the above method?

Comment: I advice you not to use multiprocessing here because its very difficult to manage the results due to the nature of expanding window calculations as each new row is dependent on the values of all the previous rows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217634/discussion-between-shubham-sharma-and-data-person).